# Marketplace Extension Recommendations

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, marketplace

I require a marketplace extension where I can heavily restrict what the logged in user sees and what they can do.

I want to be able to:

- Create/edit the listings
- Handle all of the shipping tracking input
- Handle any inquiries from buyers

I only want the seller to able to see the listing in their account. They will not able to change, add, edit or communicate with buyers. Basically it would be like viewing their order history however it will show what items of theirs are for sale.

A marketplace extension may not be the right solution so if anybody has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)